# Method Highlighting for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, vim

I'm using vim with the standard ruby-vim plugin. All of the reserved words and control-flow keywords are highlighted fine, and indentation seems to be working well. However, none of the method names are highlighted. If I call a method like `.chomp` on a variable, it's in white. If I call a built in method like `print` or `puts`, it's in white. Has anyone else run into this. Anyone have any installs or fixes for it?

Comment: Could it be the particular colorscheme used?

Comment: Normally method and variable names are not highlighted (only reserved names are, like `class`, `if`, constants...)

Comment: You can use EasyTags for that. I know there are a couple of alternative implementations on vim.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because given the ruby syntax, it's hard to distinguish between a local variable and a method call. Syntax highlighters are generally not code parsers.

See this issue as a reference:
https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/issues/6